# Not able to auto answer two prompts in batch file

Tags: batch-file, automation, command, batch-processing, command-prompt

I am trying to run a batch file which asks for `Email address` and `User Name`" to which I just want to give `enter` *(without providing email address)*. After that it will ask `Do you wish to remain uninformed of security issues ([Y]es, [N]o) [N]:` to which I will answer `Y`.

I have tried below approach with different forms.

I am trying to enter inputs automatically from a file having below contents-

> Y

And passing this file while calling batch file as below

```
somebatchfile.bat < location\input.txt
```

Now the problem is batch file is only accepting `enter` as input and failing at the second question for which I have provided input `Y`.

I have tried multiple approaches/combinations with no luck and would greatly appreciate any input.

Please find the batch file to which i want to pass auto answers as above.

```
        @echo off
::
::  Copyright (c) 2005, 2008, Oracle. All rights reserved.  
::     
::     NAME
::       emocmrsp - OCM Install Config Response Generator
::  
::     DESCRIPTION
::       This script is invoked by the user to create the response
::       file for silent installations of OCM.
:: 
::     Note
::       From a design/convention point, variables local to functions are
::       prefixed with a '_' character. Global Variables are prefixed with
::       'G_' and are entirely in upper case (The exception to this rule
::       are environment variables that are meant to abstract OS Commands
::       e.g. SED, CUT, ...)
:: 
::       Functions are listed in alphabetical order and precede the flow
::       of logic.
::     
::     EXIT CODES
::       0 - Success
::       1 - Prerequisite failure
::       2 - Invalid argument specified
::       3 - Invalid Usage
::       7 - Missing command qualifier value
::       11 - Unexpected Installation failure

:: ++
::  Construct the CCR installation directory root based upon the bin
::  directory being a child.
::  Extract the binary directory specification where this script resides. 
::  The enclosed code will come up with an absolute path. 
:: --

for %%i in (%~sf0\..) do set OCM_HOME=%%~dspi

:: Do some cmd line processing; store %* in a separate variable
:: cmd line option -calledFromC is passed only when called from
:: a C program.

set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
set CALLED_FROM_C=0
:setArgs
 if ""%1""=="""" goto doneSetArgs
 if ""%1""=="""-calledFromC""" (set CALLED_FROM_C=1) & shift & goto setArgs
 set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%CMD_LINE_ARGS% %1
 shift
 goto setArgs
:doneSetArgs

:: If we have been called from C, we exit the command processor too
:: otherwise we just exit this script (exit /b)
cscript //nologo %OCM_HOME%lib\emocmutl.vbs check_java_prereqs 
set ERRCODE=%ERRORLEVEL%
if NOT %ERRCODE% == 0 if %CALLED_FROM_C% == 1 exit %ERRCODE%
if NOT %ERRCODE% == 0 exit /b %ERRCODE%

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in ('cscript //nologo %OCM_HOME%lib\emocmutl.vbs get_env') do set __ORACLE_HOME=%%A
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in ('cscript //nologo %OCM_HOME%lib\emocmutl.vbs get_env') do set __CCR_HOME=%%B
if NOT "%ORACLE_CCR_DEV%" == "" ( for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in ('cscript //nologo %OCM_HOME%lib\emocmutl.vbs get_env') do set CCR_CONFIG_HOME=%%C )
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%A in ('cscript //nologo %OCM_HOME%lib\emocmutl.vbs get_env') do set __JAVA_HOME=%%D

set __OCM_ENDPOINT=
if NOT "%ORACLE_OCM_SERVICE%" == "" set __OCM_ENDPOINT=-Docm.endpoint=%ORACLE_OCM_SERVICE%

set __OCM_LOG=
if NOT "%CCR_DEBUG%" == "" set __OCM_LOG=-DOCM_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG

set __ORACLE_CCR_TESTS=
IF NOT "%ORACLE_CCR_TESTS%" == "" set __ORACLE_CCR_TESTS=-DORACLE_CCR_TESTS=%ORACLE_CCR_TESTS%

set __OCH_HOME=
if NOT "%ORACLE_CONFIG_HOME%" == "" set __OCH=-DORACLE_CONFIG_HOME=%ORACLE_CONFIG_HOME%

::  Use the OH as CCR_CONFIG_HOME to force the use of config parameters strictly
::  from the binary home, unless CCR_CONFIG_HOME has been set by the caller.
%__JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe %__OCM_LOG% %__OCM_ENDPOINT% %__ORACLE_CCR_TESTS% -DOCM_ROOT=%OCM_HOME% -DORACLE_HOME=%__ORACLE_HOME% -DCCR_CONFIG_HOME=%CCR_CONFIG_HOME% %__OCH% -jar %OCM_HOME%lib\emocmclnt.jar %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

Comment: Can we please see the batch file code.

Comment: Without seeing the batch file, I believe your second question is coming from the `CHOICE` command and the only valid choice is `N` because the code is using `/C N`.  The reason I say this is because CHOICE displays the list of valid answers in brackets and that is what your example is showing. You example shows that `N` is the only valid answer to the question.

Comment: I tried giving input for second question as `N` but got the same result _not accepting the input_ 
I ran the batch file manually also and there it is accepting both the inputs as it should (first `enter` and then `Y`).

Comment: The batch file I want to run is `emocmrsp.bat` which will create `ocm.rsp` response file after accepting the inputs.

Comment: we really can't help unless you show us the batch file code.  StackOverFlow was specifically created to help with code related questions. If you can't show us the code then we can only make wild guesses which just wastes everyone's time.

Comment: I have edited my post and mentioned the complete batch file code

Comment: The other approach i have tried is -

`(echo.
echo Y
echo.)| emocmrsp.bat`

but no luck. This is one also accepted only first input but not the second one i.e "Y". It shows error saying "invalid value specified".

Comment: There isn't a single `SET /P` or `CHOICE` command in that batch file code. So I do not know where you are getting any prompts for input from.